# C#.Net Convert string to double and int handling empty string

Tags: c#, typeconverter, string

I am trying to convert a **_string[1] to double** and **_string[2] to Int**

this string array is generated dynamically.

**string value can be empty or 1.1 or 1 or .1**
 how can i handle this.

i trying doing like this.

```
string locale;
locale = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages[0];
CultureInfo culture;
culture = new CultureInfo(locale);
 double cValue = Double.Parse(_string[1], culture.NumberFormat)
int sValue = Int32.Parse(_string[2], culture.NumberFormat)
```

this sometime give me invalid input when there is empty string or decimal string

Comment: How should an empty string be parsed to a double?! What should that give?

Comment: for empty or invalid input parse double to 0.00 and for int just 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the double you could use a ternary operator like this

```
double d = Double.TryParse(_string[1], out d) ? Convert.ToDouble(_string[1]) : 0;
```

In order to make it safe you could either use a try-catch or the Double.TryParse method which is a better option.

If you want to display this, you will get 0 as an output. You can turn that into a 0.00 with the following line

```
string output = (String.Format("{0:0.00}", cValue));
```

Comment: Unfortunately Convert.ToDouble will throw an exception if the input doesn't represent a valid number, whereas TryParse won't.

Comment: @HaBo.  Ok, I see.  However your code is inefficient.  On success or failure you do TryParse and also Convert.ToDouble both of which succeed or fail.  There's no point, a single TryParse is all you need.

Comment: I've completely missed that point. I thought that TryParse would only try to parse and return a bool if it CAN be parsed. Inefficient but still a working one liner.

Answer (score 6):

You can use double.TryParse.

```
// There's no need to initialize cValue since it's used as an 
// out parameter by TryParse which guarantees initialization.
// If TryParse fails the output parameter will be set it to 
// default(T), where T is double in this case, i.e. 0.

double cValue; 

if( Double.TryParse( line[8], out cValue ) )
{
    // success (cValue is now the parsed value)
}
else
{
    // failure (cValue is now 0)
}
```

or if you need to specify the culture

```
if(double.TryParse(line[8], NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out cValue))
{
}
```

If you really want to be concise then you can simply use this:

```
double cValue;
Double.TryParse( line[8], out cValue );
```

The extra lines above were just for demonstration.

Comment: Thanks I choose to go this way

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
double cValue = 0.0;
int sValue = 0;

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_string[1]))
{
   cValue = Convert.ToDouble(_string[1]);
}

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_string[2]))
{
    sValue = Convert.ToInt32(_string[2]);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k.aspx

If your string is null or empty it wont try to convert it. It will just be 0.0 or 0.

Comment: But my case is if string is empty?

Comment: But it will throw an exception if fails, your choice mostly depends on how you want to do error handling. String empty will throw an exception, converting that case to 0 will always require an extra check.

Comment: Doesn't handle empty string.

Comment: Changed to handle empty strings.